# 422 (Unprocessable Entity) POST using rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, controller

I just started using ruby on rails a few days ago. I am trying to send data from html tags to a ruby function using ajax.

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/ajax/ounces 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

I am calling the javascript function using an html button onclick attribute:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:24%;" type="button" onclick="ounces_fn()">Fluid Ounces</button>
```

Here is my ajax call using javascript:

```
<script>
    function ounces_fn() {
        var meas1 = $("#m1").val().replace( /^\D+/g, '');
        var meas2 = $("#m2").val().replace( /^\D+/g, '');
        var meas3 = $("#m3").val().replace( /^\D+/g, '');
        var meas4 = $("#m4").val().replace( /^\D+/g, '');
        $.post('/ajax/ounces', {
             num1: meas1,
             num2: meas2,
             num3: meas3,
             num4: meas4
        }, function(data) {
             alert("success!");
             $("m1").val(data[0].result.toString() + "oz.");
             $("m2").val(data[1].result.toString() + "oz.");
             $("m3").val(data[2].result.toString() + "oz.");
             $("m4").val(data[3].result.toString() + "oz.");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here is my controller:

```
post '/ajax/ounces' => 'welcome#ajax_ounces'
```

And here is my ruby function:

```
def ajax_ounces
    numArray = [params["num1"].to_f, params["num2"].to_f, params["num3"].to_f, params["num4"].to_f]
    returnArray = Array.new(4);
    i = 0

    while i < numArray.length do
        returnArray[i] = numArray[i] / 30
        i += 1
    end

    respond_to do |format|
          format.json {render :json => {:result => returnArray}}
    end
end
```

I checked many different sites, but I could not relate any of it to what I was working on. I appreciate any help you can give. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error could cause because of the CSRF token.

Try to add this line on top of controller.

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy.. Thank you sir. You saved me a lot of time. Now I just have to fix my ruby function xD